# How to export equal as string (laravel-Excel)

Tags: excel, laravel

I want to export equal sign as string, not formula, at Laravel-Excel.

I use Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel.

```
$output = [[1,2,3],["===",5,6],[7,8,9]];
//example

      Excel::create('outputs', function($excel) use($output) {
          $excel->sheet('Sheet 1', function($sheet) use($output) {
              $sheet->fromArray($output,NULL,'A1',true,false);
          });
      })->export('xls');
```

error message:

PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception
Sheet 1!A2 -> Formula Error: An unexpected error occured

Comment: Try using a single quote in front of the equal sign. In Excel itself, that is the escape character.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
However, I tried that way, single quote appears in front of equal , like '===

Comment: Alright, then you might wanna try [a different Value Binder](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/custom-formatting-values.html). I've not used this feature at all so far, but it sounds like `DataType::TYPE_STRING` or `DataType::TYPE_NUMERIC` could be what you need.

Comment: Thank you so mach Namoshek.
I resolved this.
I used  setCellValueExplicit('A2',"===",\PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING); and foreach, instead of fromArray().